# Comparison of cell counts with a right censoring

Tags: nonparametric, normality-assumption, censoring

I have cell counts related to the action of different microorganisms and I want to compare their distribution. It's supposed they follow a normal distribution after a log transformation, but I can't register all the data due to the limit of measuring instrument, so I obtain a very similar normal curve but it's cut in the point in which I can't register the data, and if I run a K-S test, it doesn't support the normality hypothesis (but n is large).

My questions:

I find this can be an usual problem, so how would you demonstrate normality in these cases? or is it impossible?

I think a Kruskal-Wallis test could works in my case, but I don't know if I have to take into account something else. Someone has suggested me to use an ANOVA due to my n is very high (n>2000) in each microorganism, despite the lack of normality, is this right?

After reading comments I think I have a right censoring. I have seen in survival analysis is used a Kaplan-Maier estimator, but this case is different. Would it be better just remove censored data and run a non-parametric test?

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "register the data" and what the nature of these "technical difficulties" is?  It sounds like you may have censored data: choosing an appropriate procedure for such data depends on the nature of the censoring.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to be concise. The used machine only can count until a limit (100000) so counts over that limit are registered as "over 100000" and this is the problem, instead of the decreasing curve of the normal distribution I have an over 100000 group which is not very useful.

Comment: That is called *right censoring.*  The issue you face is not one of testing normality but of appropriately handling the censored data.  It would help for you to edit your question to reflect that more explicitly, rather than relying on readers to look through these comments.  In particular, please clarify what you mean by "comparing" counts: do you wish to compare two distributions, two means, or something else?

Comment: Even without the censoring (which is a big issue), why would *counts* be asserted to be 'normal after a log transformation'? What's the basis for such an assertion?

Comment: @Glen_b I use a standarized transformation which is consensed and accepted for this case. But my sample size is bigger than usual. The curve is visually very similar to normal distribution and the cut point is close to the end, but I don't have an statistical evidence of normality. I don't fully trust in K-S test, but I suppose the censored data has also an influence in a normality test.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your comment, I have changed my question.

Comment: @Glen_b Although theory suggests square roots of counts should be approximately Normal (for largish counts), in practice a log transformation frequently works as well or better.

Comment: @whuber I think I need some convincing that it could be better (leaving aside the issue with log-0). The approximate variance-stabilizing transform is square root, while the one that approximately takes $\gamma_1$ (moment skewness) to zero (often called the 'symmetrizing transformation') is the $\frac{2}{3}$ power (see Anscombe residuals for example). That is if the mean is not so small that the discreteness is an issue (at which point we run into the log-0 problem left aside earlier), the square root is already too strong. There are other reasons one might use the log with a Poisson

Comment: @whuber Under some conditions I could accept 'approximately normal after a log transform' ... but that (that at best it's approximately normal) is the very point of my initial comment there. One shouldn't expect a hypothesis test to fail to reject ('support normality' was the way the OP put it) with large $n$. There are other issues but I thought that realization was essential to get through first.